# Create React App - Re-load slow. Speed up options

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a fairly big create-react-app project production build had 4 bundles (after gzip):

- 183kb
- 139.96kb
- 130.41kb
- 44.06kb

But for the development server file changes that cause re-loading are starting to take a long time 10-20 seconds, which is super frustrating for development.

Are there any options for improving this without ejecting? I can't seem to find much.

The only thing I have found to increase re-compile speed is to reduce the size of my node_modules using tree-shaking. But I can only go so far with this. Without just removing things that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One strategy you can use is to be selective about which bundles you compile. If you're only modifying one page or one section of your react app at a time for a while, you can set a global variable with the name of the webpack entry you're working on, then write a quick function that only builds things that are required for everything and the page/section of the app you're currently working on. You might run something like:

```
MY_CURRENT_ENTRY='fooPage' <whatever command you run to compile everything>
```

and then your config can parse the global variable and, if it exists, only build the required and referenced parts of your project.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not super familiar with create-react-app. I'd take a look at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#analyzing-the-bundle-size - there seems to be some good tooling for investigating code bloat.

It also sounds like it create-react-app puts everything in one app, so if you keep it all in one project it could become gigantic. One of your options could be to split disconnected parts of your app into smaller apps (the front end version of microservices).